# Algoritmo para cálculo de consumo de energia residencial ou industrial em javascript ou typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

**Olá colegas de profissão, estou criando um componente no Angular(5+) em que eu preciso de um algoritmo para realizar esse cálculo de consumo de energia**

No caso da opção potência estar selecionada

Eu informo a:

1. potência
2. Utilização (h/dia)
3. Tarifa (R$/kWh)

Que deveria retornar algo do tipo:

```
opções escolhidas:
potencia 0.01 kW
tarifa 0.77 R$/kWh
utilização 8 horas por dia

resultados:       
    diário R$  0.06

    mensal R$  1.85

    anual R$  22.48

    decênio R$  224.84
```

No caso de tensão e corrente:
Eu informo:

1. Tensão (V)
2. Corrente (A)
3. Utilização (h/dia)
4. Tarifa (R$/kWh)

Que deveria retornar algo do tipo:

```
Opções escolhidas:
potencia 0.05 kW
tarifa 0.77 R$/kWh
utilização 8 horas por dia

Resultados:
Gasto por período

diário R$  0.31

mensal R$  9.24

anual R$  112.42

decênio R$  1,124.20
```

Comment: Tem como vc postar o que vc tentou?

Comment: Oi amigo, vou já postar aqui

Comment: @EduardoVargas postei logo abaixo o código que utilizei para resolver o problema.

Answer (score 1):

Potência é uma grandeza física calculada pela taxa de variação de energia sobre a taxa de variação no tempo:

```
P = ΔE/Δt
```

Onde t é o instante de tempo em que o valor da energia é E. Essa "velocidade" com que a energia varia é denominada potência. Para o cálculo da energia temos:

```
P.Δt = ΔE
```

Essa variação representa o consumo de energia (quanto de energia foi adicionado ao sistema elétrico da casa, por exemplo).
Se o preço da energia é x, temos que o valor pago será `ΔE.x` e o tempo `Δt` é quem vai determinar se o gasto foi diário, semanal ou mensal.

A unidade de medida do resultado `ΔE.x = P.Δt.x` será o produto das unidades de medida da potência, do tempo e do preço unitário da energia.

No caso de ser informado corrente elétrica e tensão, podemos calcular através da lei de Ohm a potência irradiada pelo resistor como `P=V.i`, onde V é a voltagem (tensão, ddp) e i é a corrente elétrica.
Neste caso então `ΔE.x = P.Δt.x = V.i.Δt.x`

Para 8 horas diárias com um preço de 0,77 R$/kWh Temos um consumo diário de:

```
VALOR = ΔE.0,77 = P.8.0,77 = 6,16.P
```

Caso seja fornecida a potência P, basta substituir. Caso seja fornecido tensão e corrente, `P=V.i`. Portanto `VALOR` deve ser multiplicado por 7 para o gasto semanal, por 30 para mensal e 30*12 para anual e assim por diante.

Answer (score 0):

Bom pessoal, obrigado pela ajuda, consegui fazer a função no Typescript, segue o código.

```
paymentValue() {
 const watt_hour = this.potency * this.hour;
 const kilowatts = (watt_hour / 1000);
 this.kwh = kilowatts;    
 const kilowattsByDay = (kilowatts * this.days);
 this.kwh_days = kilowattsByDay;
 const addedTaxValue = kilowattsByDay * this.tax;    
 this.resultValue = addedTaxValue.toFixed(2);
}
```

Basicamente o que eu faço aqui, é receber os valores de potência, dias de utilização, horas, converto esses dados para kwh e faço a multiplicação pela taxa de energia por kwh.

o toFixed(2), no final do código remove os zeros a direita do resultado final do valor de gasto mensal por kwh que o cliente irá pagar.